# How to select only the characters appearing before a specific symbol in a SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have strings in a database like this:

```
firstname.lastname@email.com/IMCLientName
```

And I only need the characters that appear before the @ symbol.

I am trying to find a simple way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100)
SET @email = 'firstname.lastname@email.com/IMCLientName'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@email,0, CHARINDEX('@',@email))
```

Comment: What happens if the character isn't found? e.g. If `SET @email = 'firstname.lastname.email.com'`, what would be selected in this example?

Comment: @SpikeX an empty string would be selected.

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Ian Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084/ian-nelson)'s example we could add a quick check so we return the initial value if we don't find our index.

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100)
SET @email = 'firstname.lastname.email.com/IMCLientName'

SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@',@email) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(@email,0, CHARINDEX('@',@email))
            ELSE @email
        END AS email
```

This would return 'firstname.lastname.email.com/IMCLientName'.  If you used 'firstname.lastname@email.com/IMCLientName' then you would receive 'firstname.lastname' as a result.