# How can I change the results of a field in a SQL query to only include characters up to the first underscore?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table `ITEM`:

```
NO_ITEM    LABEL 
121_54_7   aaaaaa
32_5       jjjjjj
6          88888
9987_54_4  oooooo
```

What I want:

```
NO_ITEM    LABEL 
121        aaaaaa
32         jjjjjj
6          88888
9987       oooooo
```

Just select the first data by omitting the rest after _.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299176/how-to-select-only-the-characters-appearing-before-a-specific-symbol-in-a-sql-se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NO_ITEM, 1, CHARINDEX('_', NO_ITEM + '_')) AS NO_ITEM,
    LABEL,
FROM table
```

Comment: You need to pad; `SUBSTRING(NO_ITEM, 0, CHARINDEX('_', NO_ITEM + '_'))` for cases when there is no `_`