# CASE statement to combine two columns except when first characters not similar

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to do a `CASE` statement that combines two columns that are not alike. However, these two columns are names and the name could actually be the same except it might sometimes contain a suffix. So for instance, I want to bring back the following:

```
LastName1   | LastName2
------------------------
Ross        | Ross, Jr.
Lee         | Lee
Smith       | Collins
Martin      | Martin
Pierce, Sr. | Pierce
```

So, my statement looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LastName1 <> LastName2 THEN LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2 ELSE LastName1 END AS LastName
```

This returns the results as such:

```
LastName
---------
Ross, Ross, Jr.
Lee
Smith, Collins
Martin
Pierce, Pierce, Sr.
```

But I would like to use a `NOT LIKE` (or something similar) and if the first few characters of the `LastName1` column are similar to `LastName2`, only bring back one instance of the name. So my result set would look like:

```
LastName
---------
Ross
Lee
Smith, Collins
Martin
Pierce
```

Comment: probably better to use a fuzzy matching algorithm eg Jaro-Winkler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448297/fuzzy-grouping-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use left to take the first *n* characters. It is pretty clean LEFT(col, *n*)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN left(LastName1,4) <> left(LastName2,4) 
          THEN LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2 
       ELSE LastName1 END AS LastName
```

But this will be prone to getting false positives, be carful with your data set and the number of characters you select on. In you example you have **,** which break the data from the suffix. If that is consistent you could select all the text before **,**. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299176/how-to-select-only-the-characters-appearing-before-a-specific-symbol-in-a-sql-se)

Answer (score 2):

I would extend your comparison using `like` comparison:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LastName1 like LastName2 + '%' THEN LastName1
             WHEN LastName2 like LastName1 + '%' THEN LastName2
             ELSE LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2 
        END) AS LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CHARINDEX` to determine whether one of the LastNames subsumes the other. e.g. it appears you want the 'lessor' of the last names if they are similar:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN CHARINDEX(LastName1, LastName2 ) > 0
    THEN LastName1
  WHEN CHARINDEX(LastName2, LastName1 ) > 0
    THEN LastName2
  ELSE 
    LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2
END AS LastName
```

This will obviously backfire if a customer has a double-barelled name, e.g. `Fred James Jameson` would wind up as just `Fred James` (or `Jameson`).

Answer (score 0):

Would the following modification work?

```
   SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN LastName1 <> SUBSTRING(LastName2, 1, LEN(LastName1)) THEN LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2 
        ELSE LastName1 
        END AS LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but how about:

```
Select case 
   When charIndex(lastName1, LastName2) <> 0 then lastName2
   When charIndex(lastName2, LastName1) <> 0 then lastName1
   Else lastName1 + lastName2 End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTRING or LEFT

SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(LastName1, 1, 4) <> SUBSTRING(LastName2, 1, 4) THEN LastName1 + ', ' + LastName2 ELSE LastName1 END AS LastName